# Ajax call only getting some of data in Chrome, all of it in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, parse-platform

First of all, this works perfectly in Firefox and Internet Explorer. I have an ajax call that is retrieving data (the review and the rating). This is what becomes the output or data for profile.php. The problem is that in Chrome, I'm not getting back the $review variable. I'm getting everything else but that. It's not even showing up in the Chrome developer tools page source.

It works as it should in Firefox and IE, without any problems.

The ONLY place the submitted text shows up in Chrome is in the "Request Payload" section under the "Headers" tab under "Network". I've tried messing with the contenttype but it only made things worse.

The form:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="reviewwrap"><form id ="enterreview" name="enterreview" method="post" action="/upload.php?<?php echo $whoseprofile;?>"><textarea maxlength="4000" class="reviewinput" id="review" name = "enterreview" placeholder="Write your review!"></textarea><div class="ratingcontainer"><input id="inputy" type="number" class="rating" name = "stars" min=0 max=5 step=1 data-size="xs" data-show-caption="false" data-show-clear="false"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="enterreview" id="reviewbutton">Review</button></form></div>
```

Here's the ajax call in profile.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#reviewbutton').on('click', function() {
       $("#enterreview").submit(function(e) {
           var formObj = $(this);
           var formURL = formObj.attr("action"); // "/upload.php"
           var formData = new FormData(this);

           $.ajax({
               url: formURL,
               type: 'POST',
               data: formData, //Stops working correctly if I change this

               mimeType: "text/html",
               contentType: false, //Stops working correctly if I change this
               cache: false,
               processData: false,
               success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                   alert(data);
                   $('#reviewsection').prepend(data);
                   $('.reviewinput').val('');

               },
               error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   alert(jqXHR);
               }
           });
           return false;
       });

   });

});
```

Here's upload.php:

```
<?php 
require 'autoload.php';

$app_id = (censored);
$rest_key = (censored);
$master_key = (censored);

use Parse\ParseClient;
use Parse\ParseObject;
use Parse\ParseQuery;
use Parse\ParseACL;
use Parse\ParsePush;
use Parse\ParseUser;
use Parse\ParseInstallation;
use Parse\ParseException;
use Parse\ParseAnalytics;
use Parse\ParseFile;
use Parse\ParseCloud;
use Parse\ParseRelation;
use Parse\ParseSessionStorage;

session_start();
ParseClient::initialize( $app_id, $rest_key, $master_key );

$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

if ($currentUser) {

//If it's a review
if(isset($_POST['enterreview'])){
header("Content-type:text/HTML");
$review = $_POST['enterreview'];
$star = $_POST['stars'];
$whoseprofile = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];

$reviews = new ParseObject("Reviews");
$reviews->set("text", $review);
$reviews->set("User", $whoseprofile);
$reviews->set("Rating", $star);

$reviews->save();

        //POPULATE REVIEWS

        $query = new ParseQuery('Reviews');

    $query->equalTo("User", $whoseprofile);
    $query->descending('createdAt');
    $query->limit(6);

    $results = $query->find();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) { 

    $review = $results[$i]->get("text"); //This is the problem variable.
    $date = $results[$i]->getCreatedAt();
        $commentrating = intval($results[$i]->get("Rating"), 10);   
        header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
         echo '<input id="input-id' . $i . '" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=1 data-size="xs" data-show-caption="false" data-show-clear="false" readonly="false">
    <p class="review">' . $review . '</p>' . //The problem variable.
    '<script>

        $("#input-id' . $i . '").rating("update", ' . $commentrating . ');

    </script>'
    ;
}

exit();
}




} else {

header("Location: /login");
exit();

}

?>
```

I would appreciate any help at all. It's been one thing after another.

[image]

**EDIT:**
I fixed the problem by changing the submit button's name to something else. It had the same name as the form. Apparently this causes a problem in Chrome, and I guess from now on, I'll be making sure I don't give them the same names. I appreciate everyone's help, and I did learn a good bit about other things I was doing wrong in the process. Thanks!

Comment: Does your AJAX request return the correct data in all browsers? In other words, is the problem that Chrome isn't *getting* the data, or isn't *displaying* it?

Comment: It returns all the correct data in IE and Firefox. In Chrome, it correctly returns the rating that the user submits along with the review; however, the review itself is not returned in Chrome.

Comment: I wonder if `header("Content-type:text/HTML");` needs to be `header("Content-type: text/html");`

Comment: I would check the server log what request has hit it.

Comment: Your code has major bugs: You're doing a `header()` call inside a loop, while also doing `echo` calls. That's going to flood your output with "headers already sent" warnings. If it's NOT getting flooded, then your php install is running with warnings/errors disabled,w hich is generally a bad thing to start with: you can't debug stuff if you just supress any errors.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. I'm editing my post with a picture.

Comment: Yeah, the header call was a desperate thing I tried. It is bad though and it didn't help anything, so i'm am removing it. Thanks!

Comment: Tried changing it to 'header("Content-type: text/html");", still nothing. :/

Comment: Fixed the problem. The button had the same name as the form. I didn't know this would cause a problem. Still learning. Thanks for the help!